# Reverse URL resolution for Spring Boot GetMapping

Tags: java, django, spring, spring-boot, url

I am currently writing a Spring Boot REST API and wanted to do a reverse resolution of a URL that is defined in a `GetMapping`. In the Django web framework there is a method for doing that: [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse). But I was not able to find anything like that for Spring Boot.

I am looking for something like this:

```java
package help.me.stack.overflow;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api")
public class SomeController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/items/{filter}/blob")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getItems(@PathVariable String filter, @RequestParam String sorting) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("here you go");
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/give-me-url")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getTheUrl() {
        return resolveUrl(SomeController.getItems, "foo-filter", "foo-sorting");
        // should produce "api/items/foo-filter/blob?sorting=foo-sorting"
    }
}
```

Does something like that exist? How can I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, you can use `WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo(...)` from Spring HATEOAS:

```
linkTo(methodOn(SomeController.class).getItems("foo-filter", "foo-sorting")).withSelfRel()
```

See [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-hateoas-tutorial) for more examples